# How to call a method when AVAudioPlayer stops playing

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to know and change UIImageView when AVAudioPlayer stops playing. I am working on it but I couldnt figure this out yet. Is there any way?. My code is below

```
 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:ttsOutWav]) {
    audioPath1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ttsOutWav] error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        [audioPath1 play];

        NSLog(@"should be played");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in creating audio player:%@",[error description]);
    }
}
else{NSLog(@"such file doesnt exist");}
```

Comment: What about the `UIImageView` do you want to change?

Comment: I ll change it if i will know when AVAudioPlayer will finish playing, I just told it for people understand why i need to know AVAudioPlayer's call back method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this delegate method so this method will call back,

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

}
```

and the following delegate when there is error in decodeing

```
- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{


}
```

as you can also get an example on AVAudio Player on this site
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/10/01/tutorial-playing-audio-with-avaudioplayer/

Comment: @trojanfoe can you please tell me what is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I've never done it myself, but I would expect that you need to set the [`AVAudioPlayerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate)  delegate class and implement the following method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
                       successfully:(BOOL)flag
```